# Tensorflow (CPU-only) doesn't work in Windows Server 2016 (VM)?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I installed python 3.6.5 (64-bit) and tensorflow (CPU-only) in Windows Server 2016 (VM). The installation seems fine but I had following errors (stack details removed) when try to run tensorflow python shell:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

I did search and found a few answers about missing dll, nvidia libs but none works for me. Here's the recap:

1. I'm using tensorflow CPU-only so nvidia libs should not be required.
2. `MSVCP140.DLL` is already installed and is set in `PATH`

I did this in two different VMs but neither works. However I did same steps in Windows Server 2012 (VM) and it worked after I installed c++ Redistributable 2015! So I'm wondering if there's any compatibility issue in Windows Server 2016 (and/or VM only)?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9469 googled for `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal` "Please also check if your CPU supports AVX if you have installed tensorflow 1.6. I got this error since my CPU does not support AVX, so I had to downgrade to tensorflow 1.5."

Comment: @DanielF Thanks a lot! downgrade to 1.5 does work for me!!! So from 1.6, tensorflow won't work anymore for CPU that doesn't support AVX?

Comment: I don't know. But would you mind telling me if you are using an AMD CPU and which virtualization software you are using?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_windows "Prebuilt binaries will use AVX instructions" maybe you can build non-AVX binaries. Not sure if it is worth it.

Comment: @DanielF, it's VMWare vSphere, compatibility: ESXi 5.1 and later (VM version 9) Guest OS: Windows Server 2016. CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz 2.6GHz 2 processors